# Transposing labels on a continuous scale [waterfall graph, R]

Tags: r, ggplot2, customization, axis-labels

I am customizing a waterfall graph and am almost at the end result, except for the labels on what is now the x-axis (after `coord_flip()`). My now x-axis simply sums to 100% and, while using `scale_y_reverse()` after `coord_flip()` has helped me keep the bar hierarchy intended, it set the scale at `limits = c(100, 0)` instead of what I wanted to still keep `limits = c(0, 100)`. This is the correct way to handle it, except that for my use it does not matter as I am only trying to visualize increments in percentages.

Here is a reprex:

```
data_fig <- data.frame(class = rev(c("Class A", "Class B", "Class C", "Other Classes")),
                       values = rev(c(15, 25, 50, 10)))

waterfalls::waterfall(
    .data = data_fig,
    rect_width = 0.7, 
    fill_by_sign = FALSE,
    put_rect_text_outside_when_value_below = FALSE,
    rect_border = NA,
    total_rect_border_color = NA,
    draw_axis.x = "none") +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_y_reverse()
```

What I have tried:

- setting `limits = (0, 100)` in the `scale_y_reverse()`; rows are removed.
- set `axis.text.x = element_blank()` and tried overwriting manually, but error related to continuous scale.
- playing with the order of data, `coord_flip()` and `scale_xy_reverse()` in different ways.
- tried building a waterfall plot with `geom_rect()`/`geom_segment()` but somehow can't get around this specific issue (also as I understood waterfalls lib uses these functions).

I appreciate any ideas of how to keep `limits = (0, 100)` and the remaining of the graph elements as is. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: (1) I think `coord_flip()` is deprecated in ggplot2_3.5.0, it's usually better to just swap the `x` and `y` components when defining the plot aesthetics. If the `waterfalls` package doesn't support doing this manually, it might be good to open a new [issue](https://github.com/HughParsonage/waterfalls/issues) with the author. (2) It seems that `coord_flip` is already in an issue, not sure if it's the same thing: https://github.com/HughParsonage/waterfalls/issues/6.

Comment: Thank you very much @r2evans! I will experiment a bit more with this swap and see whether this is possible with `waterfalls` . Great that you flagged `coord_flip()` is already an issue, but also nice to know is deprecated. I will look up those details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying breaks and labels in reverse order to each other seems to generate the result you are after:

```
waterfalls::waterfall(
  .data = data_fig,
  rect_width = 0.7, 
  fill_by_sign = FALSE,
  put_rect_text_outside_when_value_below = FALSE,
  rect_border = NA,
  total_rect_border_color = NA,
  draw_axis.x = "none") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks=c(100, 75, 50, 25, 0), labels=c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100))
```

[image: waterfall with correct x-axis labels]

Comment: Great @ReelSaemon! That's it. Breaks and labels worked this time. Thank you very much. (Sorry can't upvote as this is my first question/low reputation etc.)

Comment: @franca, you should have enough reps now to upvote this answer :-)